# How to make asynchronous function in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, angular6

In **componentOne.ts** i am sending the data through **sharedService** as,

```
  this.sharedService.sendData(this.getCheckedProduct);
```

In **componentTwo.ts** i am subscribing the data like,

```
      productList: any = [];

      getAllProducts: any = [];

      ngOnInit() {
        this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(data => {
          this.productList = data;
          this.getProduct();
        });
      }
```

I am getting the data here in productlist then i need to call the function `this.getProduct()` which has the following,

```
  getProduct() {
    let tempArray = [];
    this.productList.forEach(element => {
        this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id).subscribe(res => {
          tempArray.push(res.data);
        });
    });
    this.getAllProducts = tempArray;
  }
```

I need to pass the id `element.product_obj_id` to get the necessary data of that id..

I have **tried** changing the above like this,

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      data.forEach(element => {
        this.getProduct(element);
      })
    });
  }

  async  getProduct(element) {
    let asyncResult = await this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id).toPromise();
    this.getAllProducts.push(asyncResult['data']);
  }
```

Inside `async  getProduct(element)` function i am, getting the data of  `this.getAllProducts` but in html i am not getting the data.

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let product of getAllProducts">
 Getting data
</div>
```

If i changed the above with **async**

```
<div *ngFor="let product of getAllProducts | async">
 Getting data
</div>
```

I am getting error as,

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError
```

To explain in detail, i need to send a data through sharedservice in componentone and recieve it in componenttwo then need to get the `product_obj_id` from that shared service data.

The on passing each id, i will get the data of that particular product and i need to store the final data recieved from `this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id).toPromise();` to **getAllProducts**..

```
AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts
```

is the url ..

How to achieve it in a async way.. UPto this i am getting data

```
this.getAllProducts.push(asyncResult['data']);
```

but outside the function i am not getting the value, Also the `getAllProducts` no more working on any scenario in html..

In **scenario 1** explained at top of this question i have given the following

```
this.getAllProducts = tempArray;
```

This one gives empty array as value and so only i am trying with `async` function.

In simple words i need to get the final data from `this.getAllProducts` which will be recieved from the `service` with get method for which i need to pass an id in the url..

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign your data inside the async call like this -

```
getProduct() {
    let tempArray = [];
    this.productList.forEach(element => {
        this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id).subscribe(res => {
          tempArray.push(res.data);
          this.getAllProducts = tempArray; // Here
        });
    });
  }
```

PS: In your use case no need to use pipe `async`.

Comment: No in html i am recieving no data.. <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}--> Sowing like this..

Comment: If you do so as mentioned above in answer, your binding will automatically works whenever data is available for the view part, also try to console your data just to cross check if everything working fine

Comment: In console its working.. My exact problem is if it comes out of the service its not giving the value.. Its giving empty array as value..

Comment: If i put ```    console.log(this.getAllProducts);``` outside the service i am getting the value as ```[]``` empty array...

Comment: Yes because outside service it will become synchronous, that's the reason man!

Comment: If possible create stackblitz Ill check and update you

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncPipe` is to be applied on an `Observable`. In Your case, you are applying it on `getAllProducts` which is an `Array`, I believe. Hence you are getting that error.

Possible Solution:

1. **remove `async` from your for loop of `getAllProducts`**
2. Make `getAllProducts` return an `Observable` of your *Products*

Note: since you are looping through `productList` and calling the webapi to get the products, you might have to use `mergeMap`.

Solution 2 Sample:

I believe Solution 2 is best for you, since you `productList` contains all the *products* for which you need to hit the webapi to get the details of the *products*.

Learn MergeMap [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)

Sample code(untested & you need to add code for error handling with `catchError`):

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map, combineAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.getAllProducts = from(this.productList)
    .pipe( 
        mergeMap(element =>
            this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id).pipe(
                map(res => res['data'])
            )
        ),
        combineAll()
    )

<div *ngFor="let product of getAllProducts | async">
    Getting data
</div
```

Explanation:

since you `productList` is an `Array` and you have to loop through it to and fire a request for each `product` object in that `Array`

`from(this.productList)` makes each object in `productList` into an observable. We add a `pipe` and using `mergeMap` we can fire request for each of the `product`, hence you see `this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id)` this inside `mergeMap`. We then `map` the `response` we get from the webapi and only return data using `res['data']`. Finally we `combineAll` the response which returns an `Observable<[]>`, which we set into `getAllProducts`, hence `getAllProducts` is an `Observable` and we can use `AsyncPipe` on it.

**Edit:**

Add the following in your `constructor` instead of in `ngOnit`

```
const getAllProducts = this.sharedService.getData().pipe(
  mergeMap(data=> from(data))
).pipe( 
    mergeMap(element =>
        this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id).pipe(
            map(res => res['data'])
        )
    ),
    combineAll()
)
```

Comment: I am not expecting full code from you but expecting the skeleton how to make it.. How to make as observale etc.., Because i am a very beginner in it please help me..

Comment: Your last edit shows too many errors ```cannot find name from,map,combineAll```

Comment: you need to import all of them.

Comment: whether there is no change in the ```ngOnInit``` function??

Comment: Here i am getting a single error as ```Property 'product_obj_id' does not exist on type '{}'.``` in this line ```AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id)```

Comment: That is because `ngOnInit() {
        this.sharedService.getData().subscribe(data => {
          this.productList = data;
          this.getProduct();
        });
      }`

your `productList` is initially null.

Comment: If i give it in constructor also i am getting same error ```Property 'product_obj_id' does not exist on type '{}'```, how to get out of it??

Comment: `const getAllProducts = this.sharedService.getData().pipe(
  map(val => {console.log('products',val); return val;}),mergeMap(data=> from(data))
).pipe( 
    mergeMap(element =>
        this.appService.getRest(AppConfig.settings.product.getProducts + '/' + element.product_obj_id).pipe(
            map(res => res['data'])
        )
    ),
    combineAll()
)` replace with this and post what is being the logged

Comment: This one gives new error as, ```Property 'product_obj_id' does not exist on type 'never'.```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184314/discussion-between-j4rey-and-undefined).